# jest test only returning strings inside object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs

I'm trying to run a jest test and thought the expect, toBe part to be the problem because I thought the two objects I was comparing (data, geonames) were identical.  Turns out, they weren't.  My data object looks like this:

```
{"lat": "lat", "lng": "lng"}
```

znc my geonames logs correctly:

```
{lat: 'lat', lng: 'lng'}
```

I don't know why the test is making everything inside the object data strings and I can't figure it out.  That's why my expect toBe isn't executing.

This is my code:

```
describe('geonames', (url = 'https://geonamesapi.com', geonames = {lat: 'lat', lng: 'lng'}, 
    projectData = {
                zero: {
                    date: '03/19/2021',
                    place: 'city, state'
                },
                one: {
                    coord: 
                        {
                            lat: '', 
                            lng: ''
                        }, 
                    date: '', 
                    place: '',
                    location1: '', 
                    location2: ''
                }, 
                two: {
                    month: '', 
                    day: '', 
                    year: ''
                }, 
                three: {
                    high: '', 
                    low: '', 
                    forecast: ''
                },
                four: {
                    image: ''
                }}, place = '', date = '', place1 = '', place2 = '', place_split = '', data = '') => {

                    place = projectData.zero.place;
                    projectData.zero.date = date
                    projectData.one.date = date
                    place_split = place.split(', ')
                    place1 = place_split[0]
                    place2 = place_split[1]
                    projectData.one.place = place
                    projectData.one.location1 = place1
                    projectData.one.location2 = place2
                    projectData.one.coord.lat = geonames.lat
                    projectData.one.coord.lng = geonames.lng
    it('can get coordinates', async() => {

        fetchMock.once(url, {
            status: 200,
            statusText: 'OK',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            sendAsJson: true,
            body: JSON.stringify(geonames)
        }, {method: 'GET'});
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            body: JSON.stringify({data: 'Received Payload'}),
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        })
        .then(function(req){
            expect(req.status).toEqual(200);

            console.log(data)
            return req.json();
        })
        .then(function (json) {
            console.log(json.body);
            data = json.body;
            console.log(projectData)
            console.log(data)
            console.log(geonames)
            expect(data).toMatchObject(geonames)
            data = projectData
            return data;
        })
        .then(async function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            expect(data).toEqual(projectData);
        })
    }) 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  I had to change:

```
body: JSON.stringify(geonames)
```

TO

```
body: {geonames}
```